# UITableViewCell animateWithDuration does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uianimation

I have image view on my custom cell. All elements on cell have constraints. I have implement this method for animation my arrow. Rotation works good but without animation. I have debug cell and awake from nib method was invoked.

I have header that I built from the storyboard cell:

View controller callback:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";

    KNCategorySectionCell *sectionView = (KNCategorySectionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    sectionView.index = section;
    sectionView.delegate = self;

    KNCategoryPoxy *category = [_categories objectAtIndex:section];

    [sectionView setupViewWithState:category.state];

    sectionView.categoryName.text = category.dictionary[@"name"];

    return sectionView;
}
```

Custom cell implementation of method:

```
- (void)setupViewWithState:(KNCategoryState)state
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case KNCategoryStateStateCollapsed:
            {
                [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor red:255 green:255 blue:255]];

            } break;

            case KNCategoryStateStateExpanded:
            {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                    self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];

                [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor red:230 green:230 blue:230]];

            } break;
        }
    }
```

As I said the rotation is worked but it instantly rotate view to appropriate M_PI_2 and seems there is no animation.

I have used Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1 simulator for testing.

As additional I have implemented single tap gesture in custom cell and implemented this method:

```
- (void)singleTap
{
    [self.delegate sectionDidTappedWithIndex:self.index];
}
```

`delegate` it is my view controller which contains table that display all custom cells.

In view controller I have implemented method that set header expanded and reload data:

```
- (void)sectionDidTappedWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
        for (KNCategoryPoxy *category in _categories)
        {
            category.state = KNCategoryStateStateCollapsed;
        }

        KNCategoryPoxy *category = [_categories objectAtIndex:index];

        category.state = !category.state;

        [self.theTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Where did you call `setupViewWithState`?

Comment: as you can see it is in the delegate that build for me header. - viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: @gabbler I've little bit modified question to remove misunderstood from it. So there is two method: first declared in view controller and second that declared in custom cell. When I create my header I invoke second. Do you think that animation happen before it will added to view? Also when I tap on header view I reload all table.

Comment: @gabbler I have added more details.

Comment: You should animate the imageView in `willDisplayHeaderView` method, in `viewForHeaderInSection` imageview is not in a stable state, it is being added to the header.

Answer (score 1):

Try perform animations using **UIView.commmitAnimations()** eg:

```
 UIView.beginAnimations(“rotation”, context: nil)

    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.8)

    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

    cell.alpha = 1

    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(0))

    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

also try to perform the operation inside **willDisplayCell:** Method.

Refer this http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/ solution to perform animations inside tableview cell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19944265)

Comment: Updated the answer to elaborate the solution. @user28434